# Mark as read on delete in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'd like Outlook to mark any messages I delete to be marked as read. For bonus points, I'd like it to only do this on messages that I have opened/previewed before pressing delete since this means I've looked at the content and chosen to delete it.

I know I can set it to mark as read after x seconds when I'm looking at it, that's not what I want. I also know that I can move off the message & back on to it or right click to mark as read - still not what I want.

I'm using Outlook 2007 in case that matters.

[Edit: I just found I can at least mark as read with a keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl-Q`, but again, it'd be nice to not have to do this. More shortcuts [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-HP003084223.aspx?redir=0).]

[Edit2: I am now on Outlook 2010 :)]

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/346366/have-deleted-email-in-outlook-become-read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, I did it but won't get the bonus points I guess...

I'm running outlook 2010 so I could use a new feature called the "Quick Access" menu where you can define chains of actions as a single button with a shortcut key (unfortunally, it has to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+**NUM**, so since I wanted this action to run when I press <kbd>Delete</kbd>, I had to do an extra step. See below.)

In Outlook 2007 you can still define macros. I stole this from another entry on the same subject:

http://www.formortals.com/outlook-macro-mark-as-read-delete/

```
Sub DeleteAndMarkAsRead()
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim oMailItem As MailItem
    Dim oRSSItem As PostItem

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each oItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If oItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set oMailItem = oItem
            oMailItem.UnRead = False
            oMailItem.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can then add the macro as a button and assign a shortcut to it:

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm

Then to be able to run it when I press <kbd>Delete</kbd>, I used [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and add the following to my script file:

```
#IfWinActive Inkorgen - 
    ;
    Del::       
        Send ^+1
    return
#IfWinActive
```

The part after `#IfWinActive` is the Caption (Title) of my Outlook window ("Inkorgen" is Swedish for "Inbox" FYI...) so you'll have to change it to reflect the Caption of your Outlook window.

The `Send ^+1` tells AutoHotKey to simulate a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> keypress (that's the shortcut key for my macro (Quick Access Button)).

(There is a way of matching against the class name of the window (ahk_class), but this worked for me so I couldn't be bothered to find that out.)

Comment: As per edit just now on the question, I'm now on Outlook 2010 anyway. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Wow. An AutoHotKey script to mash the shortcut code for a custom VB macro. Quite clever! But it would be super nice for this feature to be a setting in Outlook someday.