# Have deleted email in Outlook become 'read'

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I often delete emails by hitting the 'x' when the little popup window shows a new email, so they end up in my Deleted Items, but they still show as read (so DI is bold, and there's a number in parentheses after).

Where can I set it in Outlook so that all deleted emails automatically have 'read' status?

Comment: Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but you can right click on the Deleted Items folder and choose "Mark All as Read."

Comment: Yep, I've actually been right-clicking and choosing to empty it instead, but that is the only option I've really seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commercial product, ReliefJet Essentials for Outlook (I am one of its developers), has a free feature: [Outlook Tweaker](http://www.reliefjet.com/Product/Features/OutlookTweaks#Advanced). It provides a *Mark deleted items as read automatically* feature. Just check this box and all your messages will be marked as read when they are deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately the full trial version of ReliefJet Essentials for Outlook has to be installed to get the "free" feature.  This adds all the paid for functionality of the product including buttons on the toolbars.  The "Mark deleted items as read automatically" feature does work, but the functionality reverts when the product is uninstalled, so as far as I know the only way to retain the "free" functionality is to purchase the product.

Comment: Dear Leigh Riffel, you're so wrong :-(
 1. This feature is not "free": it is **free**.
 2. You can turn the toolbars off with a pair of mouse clicks.
 3. There is no need to purchase the product if you don't need extra functionality.

Comment: And one more thing to Leigh Riffel: if you uninstall *any* product, *of course* the functionality it provides is also uninstalled.

Comment: Trial software normally should be uninstalled or purchased when the trial is complete.  Your implication is that the trial is indefinite, could you please suggest that this wording be added to the website?  Please explain your "pair of mouse clicks" as it sounds much easier than what I have found:  Right click Ribbon >> Customize Ribbon >> Uncheck ReliefJet Essentials >> OK, and Create New Email >> Right Click on Ribbon >> Customize the Ribbon >> Select ReliefJet Essentials >> Remove >> OK.

Comment: Functionality that just requires changes to registry settings ,for example, often is retained after the tweaking tool is uninstalled. I was just clarifying that this tweak is more complex than a simple registry change and requires the application (specifically the COM add-on) for the feature.

Comment: I also missed Receive New Email >> Right Click on Ribbon >> Customize the Ribbon >> Select ReliefJet Essentials >> Remove >> OK.

Comment: Dear Leigh:
1. you didn't mention Ribbon, you said "toolbars" in your first comment. From what I can tell that you have Outlook 2003, where you can turn of the toolbar with 2 mouse clicks.
2. Where did you get the info that this functionality requires registry changes? Actually, the result is achived by using an add-in.
3. See 1.

And even with 1, 3: I believe it is worth it. Remember: it is **free**.

Comment: And one more thing to Leight Riffel: you want to use **free** software, but you can't even do several mouse clicks to disable extra functions (not needed for now)? That's strange... at least. Believe me, we worked *very hard* to introduce the software of the highest quality that includes **free** benefits for everyone. We did not do any implications on indefinite trial. We just said that our product includes **free Outlook Tweaker**. And it is free indeed. We didn't say that ReliefJet Essentials itself is free or has infinite trial. And we're very sorry for our English. We're Russians.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1857/discussion-between-thims-and-leigh-riffel)

Comment: @thims, I've been using this for a while now, and I thought it was working good in 2003, but we've now went to 2010 and it doesn't seem to be working.  The Deleted Items folder is showing an unread message after I delete it in the popup.  Another point is that I now have an Iphone, and delete a lot messages through that, but when I get to my main computer, they all show in the Deleted Items box as unread.  Maybe the program could check when outlook opens up, and mark any messages in the DI as read.

Answer (score 3):

This is available now in Office 365.

File > Options > Mail > Other > Mark messages as read when deleted